# Spring boot basic guide: How to create complete folder?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm creating basic spring boot application as in [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

If I download their [completed-guide-code](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/archive/main.zip), I get the `complete` folder to run and test app.

But if I do practice as [start from scratch](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch), install prequisite, go to [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io) and config, generate starting project, create web app, create app class, and go to step `Run the Application`, I cannot find the folder `complete` as in guide, so I can't run and test app. Maybe I should run some build command to create it? So how to create it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just run that command on the project root. By that folder it might mean the root directory and nothing else.

Comment: @PraveenTiwari I do run that command in root folder but it said **.** is not command : (

Comment: just run `mvn spring-boot:run`

`./` could be used for unix like systems not windows

Comment: You don't. As the `complete` folder is how your project should look like **after you finished the tutorial**. It is the final solution... It would be great if start.spring.io could generate that and it would make all of us loose our jobs... The Maven (or Gradle depending on what you choose) build file is in the root of your project, which you named `spring-boot`.

Comment: @PraveenTiwari I do run `mvn spring-boot:run` at the root folder and it work like a charm! Thank you, could you please rewrite it as an answer, I would accept it as resolved my problem!

Comment: @M.Deinum The problem is that in that guide, they have [pre-initialized project link](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.5.5&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=spring-boot&name=spring-boot&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.spring-boot&dependencies=web) that set the folder name to `spring-boot`, not `complete`. And in https://start.spring.io/ link, default name is `demo`. So this is a mistake of this guide's author. And if he/she is a better writer, he/she should call it `root folder`.

Comment: It isn't an error, which is what I explained. The `complete` folder contains the finished project, the other directory (the root one) the sources as generated by start.spring.io. It isn't an error by the writer it is your misunderstanding.

Comment: Given you're on window, use `mvnw ...` (maybe `.\mwnw ...` will also work), not `./mvnw ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please just run `mvn spring-boot:run` (use `mvnw` if maven is not installed or not on path. Spring boot project contains `mvnw` executable) in the project root without the directory specifier.

`./` could be used for unix like systems but not windows.

Comment: Did you mean `mvnw spring-boot:run`? Because using `mvn` assumes Maven is installed and on the path.

Comment: OP had showed it was in path via one of the terminal screenshots (`mvn --version`)

Comment: Check, I had missed that!

Comment: I left a note in the answer re `mvnw` for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

`complete` folder is just the root project name in the guide. In your case, the root project name is `spring-boot`, go to `spring-boot` directory and run `./mvnw spring-boot:run`.

Comment: Actually it isn't the root project name it contains the sources of the project for **after completing the guide**. So that is how the code should look like after you finished the tutorial.